# What can we say about a not-regular level sets of a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Suppose $F : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, $M$ a smooth manifold and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a critical value. Of course $N = F^{-1}(a)$ need not be an embedded submanifold of $M$.

1. How could I say that $N$ has some form of manifold structure, either immersed or even just a topological manifold?
2. What topological properties does $N$ have beyond merely being a closed set?
3. Are there any other properties of such level sets that you personally like whatsoever?

Comment: Every closed set is a level set of a smooth function. So closedness is the only thing we can say in general

Comment: You should play around with basic examples. The first example people see when they see Morse theory is the height function on a standard torus standing on its end. Then you get figure-8's at two of the critical values, points at the other two.

Comment: @Shifrin I did think of exactly that example. That’s why I wondered if there was some manifold structure. For example immersed or embedded structure.